# Icefaces 1.8 - auto-refresh dataTable

Tags: icefaces-1.8

Any example on how to auto-refresh dataTable without refreshing other components on the page?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically refresh data table, you can use **Ajax Push** feature in ICEfaces.

What you can do is to create a thread and push updates in a loop.

Here are two article explaining Ajax Push.

Ajax Push with ICEfaces : http://bit.ly/A2Cx0

Ajax Push with ICEfaces, Using RenderManager API: http://bit.ly/2GguWr

I wrote those articles in 2009, however I hope this will help since you have tagged the question with 'icefaces-1.8'.